# Scrollview content center alignment in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview and I have added the 9 buttons to it. Now my requirement is after scrolling end I need to centre align the button which is near to the scrollview's centre . Please tell me how to write common logic to this .

[image]

Comment: "Please tell me how to write common logic to this." No - make an effort.

Comment: what is the need of this BIG image in question???

Comment: @Usman BIG image is for Center alignment example

Comment: And what about the first, second, secondlast, and last button because if u do so there will be nothing after and before that and it will look odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give u a HINT:

Take the scrollView's bounds, get midX, say X1.
Take all the visible button's frames, and then their frame's midX, say X2's.
Calculate absolute differences, between X1 and X2's, whichever button has the smallest one, scroll the scrollview to that button's frame.

Have Fun. Cheers